# each create react app takes 200MB+ how to reference modules instead of having a copy in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app

Boiler plate project created with create react app is 200MB+, with out us having wrote any code.

Most of the 200MB+ files is in the node_modules folder ( from all the lib it's downloaded). I can prevent re-download by installing most of the modules globally, but the modules still gets copied to the node_modules folder of the active project.

Is there a way to reduce the disk space size of my projects, ie. to have my active project reference the npm global libs directly as opposed to create a copy of the files in the node_modules folder.

What I've found so far:

- 'ejecting' create react app to customized: I didn't like dealing with
  the mess of dealing with and having to maintain my own ejected
  version of create react app.
- ways to prevent download: [share node.js modules across React apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701345/share-node-js-modules-across-react-apps) (install the lib globally)

Comment: suggest you delete node_modules for the previous projects, and once you need it to work with it again run npm install

Comment: Take a look at this package: [npkill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npkill)